# Why is this django annotated queryset with rawSQL values not set but raw query returns results?

Tags: python, django

The problem I have is the django queryset does not contain the data from raw sql query

```
interfaces = Interface.objects.filter(
    membership__in=membership_set
).annotate(
    utilisation=RawSQL(
        'SELECT utilisation FROM interfacestat WHERE interface.name = interfacestat.ifl AND interfacestat.date = "%s"'
        ,(recent_date,)
    ),
).order_by('name')
```

So I am using a `RawSQL` expression to populate the `utilisation` field.

I check the raw sql with `print(interfaces.query)` and run that directly on MySQL.
It returns results for the `utilisation` field on a few records - however when I loop through the queryset the `utilisation` field is always unset (None).

eg.

```
interfaces[0].__dict__
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x109b1fdf0>, 'id': 230083, 'name': 'ae1.3216', ...'utilisation': None}
```

Looping through:

```
ipdb> all = interfaces.values()
ipdb> for item in all:
    print(item.get('utilisation'))
 
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: The issue was the date interpolation, I used an f-string instead: `utilisation=RawSQL(
       f 'SELECT utilisation FROM interfacestat WHERE interface.name = interfacestat.ifl AND interfacestat.date = "{ recent_date }"'
        ,(,)
    ),`